# How to skip loginScreen and passwordScreen after launch the app

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, jetpack-compose-navigation

**Hello i would like to know How to skip the loginScreen and the passwordScreen and move to homeScreen after launching the app because i have Stored the username and password in Datastore, So how can i do that?**

**Here is my code:**

MainActivity.kt

```
setContent {
    EEETheme {
        // A surface container using the 'background'
        // color from the theme
        Surface(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            color = MaterialTheme.colors.background
        ) {
            Nav()
        }
    }
}
```

Screen Class

```
sealed class Screen(val route: String) {

  object LoginScreen: Screen(route = "LoginPage_route")
  object PasswordScreen: Screen(route = "PasswordPage_route")

}
```

Navigation.kt

```
@Composable
fun Nav() {
   val context = LocalContext.current
   val navController = rememberNavController()

   NavHost(
      navController = navController,
      startDestination = Screen.LoginScreen.route
   ) {

  composable(route = Screen.LoginScreen.route) {
     LoginScreen(navController)
  }

  composable(route = Screen.PasswordScreen.route) {
     PasswordScreen(navController)
  }

  composable(route = Screen.Home.route) {
     Screen_A_with_WithTopBar(navController)
  }

}
```

LoginScreen.kt

```
@Composable
fun LoginScreen(navController: NavController) {
   Column(
      horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
      verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
      modifier = Modifier
         .fillMaxSize()
   ) {

  val context = LocalContext.current
  var username by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
  Text(text = "Login", fontSize = 33.sp)

  Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))

  OutlinedTextField(
     textStyle = TextStyle(fontSize = 24.sp),
     value = username,
     onValueChange = { username = it },
     label = { Text("Enter Your username") },
     maxLines = 1
  )

  Button(onClick = {

  }) {
     Text(text = "Submit", fontSize = 33.sp)
  }
 }

}
```

PasswordScreen.kt

```
@Composable
fun PasswordLogin(navController: NavController) {
   Column(
      horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
      verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
      modifier = Modifier
         .fillMaxSize()
   ) {

  val context = LocalContext.current
  var username by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
  Text(text = "Login", fontSize = 33.sp)

  Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))

  OutlinedTextField(
     textStyle = TextStyle(fontSize = 24.sp),
     value = username,
     onValueChange = { username = it },
     label = { Text("Enter Your username") },
     maxLines = 1
  )

  Button(onClick = {

  }) {
     Text(text = "Submit", fontSize = 33.sp)
  }
 }

}
```

HomeScreen.kt

```
@Composable
fun HomeScreen(navController: NavController) {
   Column(
      horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
      verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
      modifier = Modifier
         .fillMaxSize()
   ) {
      Text(text = "Home Screen", fontSize = 33.sp)
   }
}
```

DataStore Class

```
  class StoreUserName(private val context: Context) {
   // to make sure there's only one instance
   companion object {
      private val Context.dataStore: DataStore<Preferences> by preferencesDataStore("authentication")
      val USERNAME_KEY  = stringPreferencesKey("username")
      val PASSWORD_KEY  = stringPreferencesKey("password")
    
   }

   //get the saved CompanyID
   val getUsername: Flow<String?> = context.dataStore.data
      .map { preferences ->
         preferences[USERNAME_KEY] ?: ""
      }

   //get the saved LoginID
   val getPassword: Flow<String?> = context.dataStore.data
      .map { preferences ->
         preferences[PASSWORD_KEY] ?: ""
      }


   //save username into datastore
   suspend fun saveUsername(username: String) {
      context.dataStore.edit { preferences ->
         preferences[USERNAME_KEY] = username
      }
   }

   //save Password into datastore
   suspend fun savePassword(password: String) {
      context.dataStore.edit { preferences ->
         preferences[PASSWORD_KEY] = password
      }
   }

}
```

Comment: First you should have a screen(SplashScreen) in which we call webservice to get basic data or check if user data is stored. before doing anything check if user data is stored that move user to Home screen using intent.
If you dont wanna use Splash screen then do same thing on Login screen

Comment: A simple solution would be once you login in create a cache value loggedin = true inside a database or sharedpreferences of your app. Now you have to check this value once the login activity (or the first activity that you have) starts. If the user is logged in move to another activity else stay at login.

Comment: There's a whole section outlining this situation in the Navigation docs: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-conditional

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `fun Nav()` you should check if you have credentials stored and then based on that you should set `startDestination`

for example:

```
@Composable
fun Nav() {
   val context = LocalContext.current
   val navController = rememberNavController()
   val isLoginRequired = //you condition
   NavHost(
      navController = navController,
      startDestination = if(isLoginRequired) 
      Screen.LoginScreen.route 
      else 
      Screen.Home.route
   ) {

  composable(route = Screen.LoginScreen.route) {
     LoginScreen(navController)
  }

  composable(route = Screen.PasswordScreen.route) {
     PasswordScreen(navController)
  }

  composable(route = Screen.Home.route) {
     Screen_A_with_WithTopBar(navController)
  }

}
```